# Any faster alternative to scroll using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I need to scroll till the end of the page which I am doing so using.

```
while(True):    
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

However, is there any faster approach. It is taking ages for queries in thousands.